# PaperTrail doesn't play nice with Carrierwave and `remove_previously_stored_files_after_update` option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, paper-trail-gem

I need to version images for my Rails app. I'm using Carrierwave for file uploads, and PaperTrail for versioning.

While versioning seems to work pretty well, it seems though that reifying a version doesn't play nice with Carrierwave's `remove_previously_stored_files_after_update` config deactivated: in this situation, a simple `reload` of the reified model instance doesn't work anymore, only an explicit fresh load from the database (using `Model.find 123`) works.

I have created a [demo Rails app](https://github.com/jmuheim/test-carrierwave-papertrail) to demonstrate the problem.

The `User` model mounts two uploaders:

- `AvatarUploader`, which removes the file after update (default)
- `KeepingFilesAvatarUploader`, which doesn't remove the file after update, using the `remove_previously_stored_files_after_update` option set to `false`

Code of `AvatarUploader`:

```
# encoding: utf-8

class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.id}/#{mounted_as}"
  end
end
```

Code of `KeepingFilesAvatarUploader`:

```
# encoding: utf-8

class KeepingFilesAvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.id}/#{mounted_as}"
  end

  configure do |config|
    config.remove_previously_stored_files_after_update = false
  end
end
```

The only difference is the `remove_previously_stored_files_after_update` option.

Here's the code of the `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail only: [:name, :avatar, :keeping_files_avatar]
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
  mount_uploader :keeping_files_avatar, KeepingFilesAvatarUploader
end
```

I have written some specs which demonstrate the unexpected behaviour. As they are a bit long to post, see here:

https://github.com/jmuheim/test-carrierwave-papertrail/blob/master/spec/models/user_spec.rb#L20

All specs pass except the one that I set to `pending`, here's the output:

```
  1) User versioning reloading the model after reify sets "keeping_files_avatar" to the original value
     # See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29624223/papertrail-doesnt-play-nice-with-carrierwave-and-remove-previously-stored-file
     Failure/Error: expect(user.keeping_files_avatar.file.filename).to eq 'original-image.jpg' # This upload field isn'! <<<FAILING LINE>>>!

       expected: "original-image.jpg"
            got: "new-image.jpg"

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:20:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.20704 seconds (files took 1.51 seconds to load)
4 examples, 0 failures, 1 pending
```

It would be really nice to get this to work. I don't need this functionality right now, but I don't want to add any technical debt to my project (especially this one could lead to very unforeseen problems as one usually relies on simply doing a `reload` on a model to refresh its attributes).

Answer (score 0):

Check if this will work for you

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail only: [:name, :avatar, :keeping_files_avatar]

  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
  mount_uploader :keeping_files_avatar, KeepingFilesAvatarUploader

  skip_callback :save, :after, :remove_previously_stored_keeping_files_avatar
end
```

Comment: Sadly: no, it doesn't either.